# Rust - padded array of bytes from str

Tags: rust

This rust does exactly what I want, but I don't do much rust and I get the feeling this could be done much better - like maybe in one line. Can anyone give hints to a more "rust idiomatic" way?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f139ccf6e8f88dbe92f1f1e4d7a487a

```
fn fill_from_str(bytes: &mut [u8], s: &str) {
    let mut i=0;
    for b in s.as_bytes() {
        bytes[i] = *b;
        i=i+1;
    }
} 

fn main() {
    let mut bytes: [u8; 10] = [0; 10];
    fill_from_str(&mut bytes,"hello");
    println!("{:?}",bytes);
}
```

Comment: Notice that the example code you gave will both overflow the buffer if the string is too long and cut in between code points if the last character is multi-byte encoded but doesn't fit in its entirety.

Comment: thats ok, input is checked.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to do this: the `copy_from_slice` method. If the slice and the string are the same length this is a one-liner:

```rust
fn copy_from_str(dest:&mut[u8], src:&str){
    dest.copy_from_slice(src.as_bytes());
}
```

The `copy_from_slice` method also is just a single call to `memcpy` so it is faster than your version. If you want to support different sizes a little more code is needed:

```rust
fn copy_from_str(dest:&mut [u8],src:&str){
    if dest.len() == src.len(){
        dest.copy_from_slice(src.as_bytes());
    } else if dest.len() > src.len(){
        dest[..src.len()].copy_from_slice(src.as_bytes());
    } else {
        dest.copy_from_slice(&src.as_bytes()[..dest.len()]);
    }
}
```

That function will also not panic if it winds up slicing on the boundary of a multibyte character.

Edit: [Added Plaground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6815352d74f2719c99de12d28e1e581b)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very succinctly via [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) which is implemented for `&mut [u8]`:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn fill_from_str(mut bytes: &mut [u8], s: &str) {
    bytes.write(s.as_bytes()).unwrap();
} 

fn main() {
    let mut bytes: [u8; 10] = [0; 10];
    fill_from_str(&mut bytes, "hello");
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```